# If-else condition for n-bit number

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

I want to design a ripple carry adder which will add n bit A and B number. Before adding I want to check whether any of the input is zero or not. If any value is zero, I want to return another input as output.
My script is something similar to below-

```
module RCA #(parameter n=10) (input [n-1:0] A, input [n-1:0] B,output [n-1:0] R);

wire [n-1:0] r1;
wire [n:0] carry;
assign carry[0]=0;

genvar i;
generate
for (i=0;i<n;i=i+1) begin:ripple_block
FA fa(.a(p[i]),.b(q[i]),.s(r1[i]),.cout(carry[i+1]));
end
endgenerate

if (p==0) begin:a1
assign R=q;
end

if (q==0) begin:a2
assign R=p;
end

else begin:a3
assign R=r1;
end

endmodule
```

I am getting the error

```
"Elaboration time unknown or bad value encountered for generate if-statement condition 
expression. Please make sure it is elaboration time constant."
```

Please help me find the error in the script.

Thanks
Farhana

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have used `if..else` condition in a **wrong** manner. The `if..else` condition must be used in a **procedural block**. While here, it is used inside module directly.

The compiler was expecting `if..else` inside the `generate` block. But I guess this is not the intent of your code.

Just **remove** the conditions and use **ternary operators** (`? :`) instead. So, your code looks as follows:

```
module RCA #(parameter n=10) (input [n-1:0] A, input [n-1:0] B,output [n-1:0] R);
// ...
// ...
generate
//...
//...
endgenerate

//if (p==0) begin:a1
/***Use of ternary operator here***/
  assign R= (p==0) ? q : ((q==0) ? p : r1); 
// end

// if (q==0) begin:a2
// assign R=p;
// end
// 
// else begin:a3
// assign R=r1;
// end

endmodule
```

There can be *other methods* also. Using `always_comb` or `always @(*)` are some of the alternative. For more information on ternary operator and about your question, refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17752727/if-statement-and-assiging-wires-in-verilog) link. As always, SystemVerilog [LRM 1800-2012](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&sqi=2&ved=0CBwQFjAAahUKEwjttrrN5oTJAhWOCY4KHZW5BBM&url=https%3A%2F%2Fblogs.mentor.com%2Fverificationhorizons%2Fblog%2F2013%2F02%2F25%2Fget-your-ieee-1800%2F&usg=AFQjCNFAlvMqGSNPYmdOEHLf2zTB_w4DQg&sig2=BwS5hT6f2Ull_b2hyi-jNA&bvm=bv.106923889,d.c2E) *chapter 11 and 12* can be useful.

Comment: Can I skip addition altogether if any of the input is zero? In the ternary operator I first calculate the addition and then choose one of the results. Can I do it in reverse way? This means one of the ternary assignment value will contain the whole generate block.

Comment: In verilog, when you are instantiating a module, means you are **adding hardware** to your board. You can **conditionally** add that hardware(using `if` in generate or `ifdef`) or you can **bypass** it for certain inputs, but once instantiated, you **can not remove** that. Here, you can bypass the `FA` module, but still it will remain on your board. Using ternary operator like `assign R = (A==0)? B : ((B==0)?A : r1)` will bypass `FA` by adding some MUXes to your design.

Comment: I just to make sure that the switching power reduces when any of the input is zero. If A=0, will the FA module be bypassed or r1 will still be calculated and then one of the answer will be chosen?

Comment: Here, the module `FA` is bypassed in terms of **latency**. Let's say the `FA` module takes 2 clock cycles for providing the output, but for certain input combinations, your output is predictable. So above `assign` statement shall provide outputs instantaneously,thereby decreasing the latency (even though the inputs still travel into module and r1 will still be calculated). Secondly, to decrease the power, you can add **gating** signals which would mask other signals. Clock gating procedure is quite common thing. Like `mod_clk = top_clk & clk_gate `. There are other ways also fr low pwr cons.